Calculate standard deviation within a certain range in excel
I first checked the answers this question:
Is there a way to calculate standard deviation on a range of cells only for cells where the value is greater than 0 in Excel?
I tried to use this info for a range but it doesn't work.
I.e.
It works fine for this:
=stdev(if(A1:A100>0.40,A1:A100))

But not for this:
=stdev(if(and(A1:A100>0.40,A1:A100<0.65),A1:A100))

I get the value of 0 (the stdev is not 0 for sure).
I have also tried the following, with no positive result:
=STDEV(FILTER(A1:A100,AND(A1:A100>0.40,A1:A100<0.65))

Any ideas?

I'm curious, a common use for the standard deviation is to filter out extremely high or low anomalous values from a distribution. But here, you're placing bounds on your distribution prior to taking its standard deviation, which would result in an artificially constrained std value. Nothing necessarily wrong with that, but I'm curious as to what you're using it for.

The original question is using STDEV.P(IF(A1:A100>0, A1:A100)) rather than STDEV(). Consider checking your code

"If you want to include logical values and text representations of numbers in a reference as part of the calculation, use the STDEVA function." from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stdev-function-51fecaaa-231e-4bbb-9230-33650a72c9b0#:~:text=Estimates%20standard%20deviation%20based%20on,average%20value%20(the%20mean). You should also try STDEV.S()

I have actually used STDEV.P. It works with only one IF but not with IF(AND(...
So this one does not work:
=STDEV.P(FILTER(A1:A100,AND(A1:A100>0.40,A1:A100<0.65))

AND result one TRUE or FALSE for whole set of data so in this case can't be used in FILTER. Try =STDEV.P(FILTER(A1:A100,(A1:A100>0.4)*(A1:A100<0.65))) instead

It worked thanks!
@ThomasKimber, I have data points of Copy Number ratios (where ratio of 1 is CN=2 and ratio of 0.5 is CN=1) of DNA probes. I want to see within the "heterozygous deletion" range that we give to customers (0.40 - 0.65) what is the standard deviation of the each probe. Will do the same for CN=3. Hope it's clear, but let me know if you have any questions.
